# Dynamic ORM in MySQL and other databases?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, data-modeling

The problem I have with the various ORM modules available for databases like MySQL and MongoDB is the inability to keep model information coupled with the database itself.

I want to be able to add a model to my ORM setup at runtime via an administrative HTTP interface and give it some fields that may be ascribed to various predefined data types (like 'email' or 'telephone number'). Possibly the most contentious feature I'm after is the ability to cast a field as a data type that has already been previously defined by the user as a model.

Is this just me trying to have my cake and eat it? Can anybody see a way of implementing something like this? All the ORM modules I've seen so far simply require instantiating models at application level, essentially before runtime.

It's probably worth mentioning I'm hoping to implement this in a Node environment (not a classic LAMP setup).

**EDIT:**

I take it from the lack of community bite that I may have stumbled back into the Object-Relational Impedance Mismatch issue here?

Comment: I want runtime model configuration too, but in my LAMP setup. I want to dynamically create tables and fields through the GUI, like Drupal does, but the various PHP ORMs don't seem to have any desire for this. Perhaps they consider it an ORM impedance mismatch, but personally I don't see why configuring the model at runtime is any different conceptually than before runtime.

Comment: @BenClaar Perhaps an upvote on the question? If it's something you'd benefit from... :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your solution depends on multiple drivers, you can try [light-orm](https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm). It is simple wrapper for relations dbs.